# Cardioid in complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question in complex analysis. The question is this:

- sketch the circle $|z-1|=1$. Find (geometrically) the polar equation of the image of this circle under the mapping $z \mapsto z^2$. Sketch image curve.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to give the polar equation a ticket for you. BRB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$$ | z - 1 | = 1 $$
$$ z  = e^{i\theta} + 1 $$

$$ f(z)= z^2 $$

```
                       working in the w plane now.
```

$$\rho e^{i\phi} = (1 + e^ {i \theta})^2 $$

$$\rho e^{i\phi} = 1 + 2e^{i \theta} + e^{2i \theta} $$

$$\rho e^{i\phi} =  e^{i\theta} ( e^{-i\theta} + 2 + e ^{i\theta}) $$

```
             using an identity for the complex cosine function
```

$$ \rho e^{i\phi} = e^{i\theta} (  2 + 2 cos\theta) $$

$$ \rho=  (  2 + 2 cos\theta) , (\phi = \theta )$$

```
                    Which is a cardioid in the w plane
```

Another method:

Parametric equation for the circle:

$x(t)  = cos(t) + 1$ and 
$y(t)  = sin(t) $

$f(z) = z^2 $  which takes $(u,v)$ to $(u^2 - v^2, 2uv)$

we get, after playing around a bit:

$ (1 + 2 cos(t) + cos(2t) , 2sin(t) + sin(2t) ) $

The equation of a cardioid.

Only, it should be in the form $ r = 2(1 + cos(t)) $ , same as above. So, a little work perhaps, it's the same cardioid...

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer...Can you add more detail on this?? I dont follow your answer..I am new to this complex analysis and having hard time understanding it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll rewrite an easier method in a second.

Comment: Let me know if the second method is useful, I skipped some steps. Also, it helps to graph the expression to see that the two objects are the same curve.

Comment: Thank you!! It is getting clearer.. But I have still have some questions.. 1. The word mapping $z \mapsto z^2$ means a complex function applied to z?? 2. How did you get the equation of cardioid from $(u^2-v^2, 2uv)$ to $(1+2cos(t)+cos(2t),2sin(t)+sin(2t))$?? 3. From your original answer, the purpose of $\rho$ is to porlar euqation?? and 4.If you can, can you explain how the mapping $z \mapsto z^2$ become circle to cardioid?? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, on the word mapping. messed with the parametric equations setting u = 1+cos(t) , v=sin(t). I tried to simplify it after that noticed I could get r = 2( 1 + cos(t)) and it matched what I had. Yes , I changed the form so the polar equation was always the object I was looking for, that's why it's so hard to understand! So big hint,solve it first to get the cardioid , then see if you can get the polar equation. The last point how the mapping takes the circle to the cardioid, there will be a theorem that says, any circle that passes through the origin becomes a cardioid under the z^2 map.

Comment: Thank you.. Now I understand the question. Can I ask you one more question?? I am taking a modern geometry class and my professor using Complex analysis text book.. The text book talks about the motion on complex plane.. The question I want to ask is that what is the difference between $z e^{i \theta}$ and $z+e^{i \theta}$?? How can I interpret these two?? Thanks!!

Comment: perhaps $ 4 e^i\theta $ represents a magnification factor of 4 center at origin , but $4 + e^i\theta$ would have 4 as a center and radius 1.

Comment: Thank you very much.. It was great help!!